# Where are AWS data center locations listed?

Tags: geolocation, amazon-web-services, ip-geolocation

I'm failing at Google search today.  Is there a page that lists geolocations of the various Amazon AWS server farms?

I want to use this data to pick the appropriate farm for a client on a web app, CDN-style.

(This isn't programming, but it's for the purpose of programming, and I thought it would be useful to have this question answered for public consumption.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each service's detail page (e.g. http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/, http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) provides this information.

Comment: Update: No, these pages no longer list this information

Comment: You're right. The complete information is now posted at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Answer (score 56):

Very late to the party, but in case anyone else has the same question, we've done some work to map AWS regional data centers by the fastest connection to each country (and state in US):

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/aws-datacenters

The code used to this has been open sourced:

https://github.com/turnkeylinux/aws-datacenters

Mashup of associations and worldwide underwater cables:

[image: aws-datacenters-mashup]

Regarding the GeoIP implementation, see:

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/geoip-amazon-regions

Answer (score 2):

## WikiLeaks - AmazonAtlas

Confidential AWS datacenters location has been leaked:

> 11 October 2018, WikiLeaks publishes a "Highly Confidential" internal document from the cloud computing provider Amazon. The document from late 2015 lists the addresses and some operational details of over one hundred data centers spread across fifteen cities in nine countries

https://wikileaks.org/amazon-atlas/

https://wikileaks.org/amazon-atlas/map/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> #### [datacenters.com](http://datacenters.com)

The best reference I found for tracking down the individual data center locations is datacenters.com's locations page: https://www.datacenters.com/locations

From there you can see locations and details of individual data centers like [AWS Ashburn](https://www.datacenters.com/amazon-aws-ashburn)

> #### domenech's Google Maps overlay

The other reference I cam across is from this blog post from domenech: [Amazon Web Services Google Maps: World Domination Map](http://blog.domenech.org/2013/03/amazon-web-services-world-domination-map.html)

Direct link to the map [here](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?ll=50.95842700000002%2C4.130858999999987&spn=26.684562%2C56.25&t=m&msa=0&z=4&source=embed&ie=UTF8&mid=1m6v8XPxwp0Dx4THiakRKFkZwIGE)

Answer (score 0):

An updated list here:
https://gist.github.com/atyachin/a011edf76df66c5aa1eac0cdca412ea9

Compiled from various sources including those mentioned in other answers.
Coordinates represent the location of a specific datacenter in the zone. Most availability-zones have multiple datacenters so there's no single coordinate for each AZ.